# How to use mysql_real_escape_string for an array?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, sql-injection

I want to `INSERT` a set of data submitted by $_POST (in form of array) as

```
foreach($_POST['data'] as $single) {
$set[]="('static', '$single')";
}
$sets=implode(", ", $set);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (Static, Data) VALUES $sets");
```

Where is the best place to use `use mysql_real_escape_string` to avoid SQL injection, as the data are submitted by users.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Before going to your first foreach.

```
$_POST['data'] = array_map("mysql_real_escape_string", $_POST['data']);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with this:

```
foreach($_POST['data'] as $single)
{
    $set[]="('static', mysql_real_escape_string($single))";
}
$sets = implode(", ", $set);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` (`Static`, `Data`) VALUES ".$sets."");
```